# having problem when creating a unique file name from different html files

Tags: r, text

I have different html text files and their names are text1 text2 text3... texts400. These are html files that I make R read with following command(one example):

```
text56 <- read_html("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_Ocak_2011%27deki_ulusa_sesleni%C5%9F_konu%C5%9Fmas%C4%B1 ")
```

Now I am trying to create a unique html text file and I am using following commands:

```
out.file <- "" 
file.names <- text[i] 
for(i in 1:length(file.names)) {
  file <- read.table(file.names[i],header=TRUE, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
write.table(out.file, file = "myfilename.txt",sep=";", 
         row.names = FALSE, qmethod = "double",fileEncoding="windows-1252")
```

But there is a problem in second line that is
     `file.names <- text[i]`
Since I am trying to define file names, but it does not define all files with that command. Any idea how can I overcome this problem or how can I create one unique html text file with different html text file?

Comment: Do you have a list of names called `text`. If not, `text[i]` wouldn't return anything. If yes, how are you creating this list?

Comment: I have created texts like that: `text1<- read_html("https://link1 "), text2<- read_html("https://link2 "), text3<- read_html("https://link3 ")`  ..... untill400. Other than this, should I create text list?